# Process sometimes suspends when writing to emacs

Tags: c, linux, terminal, posix

I am currently doing a mainly-for-fun project, trying to code a simple terminal emulator. So far, what I want to do is to just have a “proxy process” which only forwards terminal commands. This seems to work so far, when I call /usr/bin/nano with the code below.

However, when I try to do the same with emacs, I run into a heisenbug: Sometimes it works well, but mostly not: resizing works, but as soon as I type anything, my process gets suspended, as if I pressed Ctrl+z (which I of course did not do).

strace of emacs is a sequence of:

```
ioctl(6, FIONREAD, [0])                 = 0
poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
read(7, 0x7fff078de1d0, 16)             = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(8, [6 7], NULL, NULL, {100000, 0}) = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be restarted)
--- SIGIO (I/O possible) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigreturn(0x1d)                      = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
```

strace of my process at time of suspension is:

```
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {0x7f8964468b50, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f8963ea54a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x7f8964468a80, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f8963ea54a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x7f8964468a80, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f8963ea54a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, NULL, {0x401088, [WINCH], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f8963ea54a0}, 8) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
select(4, [0 3], [], NULL, NULL)        = 1 (in [0])
read(0, 0x7fffafd46890, 4096)           = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
--- SIGTTIN (Stopped (tty input)) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGTTIN (Stopped (tty input)) @ 0 (0) ---
read(0, 0x7fffafd46890, 4096)           = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
--- SIGTTIN (Stopped (tty input)) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGTTIN (Stopped (tty input)) @ 0 (0) ---
read(0, 0x7fffafd46890, 4096)           = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
--- SIGTTIN (Stopped (tty input)) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGTTIN (Stopped (tty input)) @ 0 (0) ---
```

My source code, compile with -lutil -lncurses:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <spawn.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <signal.h>


#ifdef __GNUC__
# define likely(x)       __builtin_expect((x),1)
# define unlikely(x)     __builtin_expect((x),0)
#else
# define likely(x)       (x)
# define unlikely(x)     (x)
#endif

int mpt; /* master pty */
pid_t pid = 0; /* child pid */
bool childexit = false;

int max (int ini, ...) {
  /* the maximum of positive integers, terminated with -1 */
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, ini);
  int ret = -1;
  while (ini != -1) {
ret = (ret < ini) ? ini : ret;
ini = va_arg(ap, int);
  }
  va_end(ap);
  return ret;
}
/* atexit */
void close_child (void) {
  if (! childexit) {
kill (pid, SIGTERM);
  }
}
void reset_term (void) {
  endwin();
}
/* signal handlers */
void sigwinch (int sig) {
  (void) sig;
  struct winsize w;
  if (ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w) != -1) {
ioctl(mpt, TIOCSWINSZ, &w);
  }
}
void sigchld (int sig) {
  (void) sig;
  //childexit = true;
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
void sigusr1 (int sig) {
  (void) sig;
  struct winsize w;
  ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
  w.ws_row = 25;
  w.ws_col = 25;
}
int main (void) {
  atexit(close_child);
  atexit(reset_term);
  char* spawnedArgs[] = { "/usr/bin/emacs", "-nw", NULL };
  char* spawnedEnv[] = { "TERM=xterm", NULL };
  size_t slave_len = 128 * sizeof(char);
  char* slave = malloc (slave_len);
  if (slave == NULL) {
fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate slave var");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  mpt = posix_openpt(O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
  if (mpt < 0) {
perror("Cannot open Master");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (grantpt(mpt) < 0) {
perror("Cannot grant Terminal");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (unlockpt(mpt) < 0) {
perror("Cannot unlock Terminal");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  while ((ptsname_r(mpt, slave, slave_len)) != 0) {
int e = errno;
if (e == ERANGE) {
  slave_len *= 2;
  slave = realloc(slave, slave_len);
  if (slave == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot reallocate slave var\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
} else {
  fprintf(stderr, "Cannot get name of terminal: %s\n", strerror(e));
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
  }
  int slavefd = open(slave, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
  if (slavefd < 0) {
perror("Cannot open Slave");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  posix_spawn_file_actions_t action;
  posix_spawnattr_t attrs;
  sigset_t set;
  sigemptyset(&set);
  posix_spawnattr_setsigmask(&attrs, &set);
  posix_spawnattr_setflags(&attrs, POSIX_SPAWN_SETSIGMASK);
  posix_spawn_file_actions_init(&action);
  posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2(&action, slavefd, STDOUT_FILENO);
  posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2(&action, slavefd, STDIN_FILENO);
  posix_spawnp(&pid, spawnedArgs[0], &action, &attrs, spawnedArgs, spawnedEnv);

  fd_set rfds, wfds;
  int sel, nfds;

  char mystdin[4096], yourstdout[4096];
  int mystdindef = 0, yourstdoutdef = 0;

  signal(SIGWINCH, sigwinch);
  signal(SIGCHLD, sigchld);
  signal(SIGUSR1, sigusr1);

  initscr (); raw (); noecho ();

  while (1) {
  begin_select_loop:

nfds = 0;

FD_ZERO(&rfds);
FD_ZERO(&wfds);

/* read if buffers are empty, write if buffers are filled */

if (mystdindef == 0) {
  FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &rfds);
  nfds = max(nfds, STDIN_FILENO, -1);
} else {
  FD_SET(mpt, &wfds);
  nfds = max(nfds, mpt, -1);
}

if (yourstdoutdef == 0) {
  FD_SET(mpt, &rfds);
  nfds = max(nfds, mpt, -1);
} else {
  FD_SET(STDOUT_FILENO, &wfds);
  nfds = max(nfds, STDOUT_FILENO, -1);
}

sel = select(1 + nfds, &rfds, &wfds, NULL, NULL);
if (sel < 0) {
  int e = errno;
  if (unlikely(e == EINTR)) {
    /* A signal has interrupted us. Well, I guess this might be
       one of the few legit uses of goto, since C99 has no good
       mechanism for continuations yet. */
    goto begin_select_loop;
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error calling select: %s\n", strerror(e));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}

if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &rfds)) {
  mystdindef = read (STDIN_FILENO, mystdin, sizeof(mystdin));
  if (unlikely(mystdindef == -1)) {
    perror("Reading from stdin");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else if (unlikely(mystdindef == 0)) {
    /* EOF */
    //exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
}

if (FD_ISSET(mpt, &rfds)) {
  yourstdoutdef = read (mpt, yourstdout, sizeof(mystdin));
  if (unlikely(yourstdoutdef == -1)) {
    perror("Reading from master");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else if (unlikely(yourstdoutdef == 0)) {
    /* EOF */
    //exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
}

if (FD_ISSET(STDOUT_FILENO, &wfds)) {
  int written = write(STDOUT_FILENO, yourstdout, yourstdoutdef);
  if (unlikely(written == -1)) {
    perror("Writing to stdout");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else if (unlikely(written < yourstdoutdef)) {
    memmove(yourstdout, yourstdout + written, yourstdoutdef -= written );
  } else {
    yourstdoutdef = 0;
  }
}

if (FD_ISSET(mpt, &wfds)) {
  int written = write(mpt, mystdin, mystdindef);
  if (unlikely(written == -1)) {
    perror("Writing to stdout");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else if (unlikely(written < mystdindef)) {
    memmove(mystdin, mystdin + written, mystdindef -= written );
  } else {
    mystdindef = 0;
  }
}
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any help, I really have no idea what could be going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't initialize the `posix_spawnattr_t` object via `posix_spawnattr_init()` (possibly causing unexpected attributes to be used) and don't destroy either the `posix_spawnattr_t` or the `posix_spawn_file_actions_t` object.

The child process neither has the pseudo terminal as its stderr (fd 2), nor as its controlling terminal. Therefore, it will partially behave as if attached to the original tty and not the new one.

The former is easy to fix via another dup2. The latter requires calling `setsid()`, invoking a non-standard function like `tcsetsid()` or a `TIOCSCTTY` ioctl in the child process; therefore, you need to move from `posix_spawnp()` to `fork()` and `execve()`.

If you don't mind using more non-standard functions, you can simplify the code using `login_tty()` or `forkpty()`.

Comment: Thank you. Forkpty makes the whola thing a lot easier. Usually I do not like forking, but in this case, I guess that is basically the best alternative.